# Get rid of Unchecked overriding: return type requires unchecked conversion

Tags: java, generics, unchecked-conversion

Example code similar to my code.

```
public interface Builder<B, A> {
  B build(A a);
}

public class ClientBuilder implements Builder<String, Integer> {
  @Override
  public String build(Integer i) {
    return i.toString();
  }
}

public abstract class Client<B> {
  protected abstract <A> Builder<B, A> getBuilder();
}

public class ClientClient extends Client<String> {

  @Override
  protected Builder<String, Integer> getBuilder() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

In my `ClientClient` class I get a warning that says the following:

`Unchecked overriding: return type requires unchecked conversion.Found 'Builder<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>', required 'Builder<java.lang.String,A>`

Is there something I can do to get rid of this error?
I could use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, but that doesn't feel right.

In my example `A` is always an `Integer` but in my real code `A` can be one of two objects.

I guess I could also have two methods in my interface like this:

```
public interface Builder<B> {
  B build(Integer i);
  B build(String s);
}
```

Comment: Note that it is recommended to use the existing JDK interfaces, so in your case you might use `Function<A,B>`.

Comment: The compiler does not lie here, `<A>`is not the type from `Builder<B, A>`, but any type passed to the method.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't overriding the method correctly:

```
protected Builder<String, Integer> getBuilder() {
    return null;
}
```

You're missing the type variable.

Either declare it correctly:

```
protected <A> Builder<String, A> getBuilder() {
    return null;
}
```

or change the class declaration to allow you to provide the second type parameter:

```
public abstract class Client<B, A> {
  protected abstract Builder<B, A> getBuilder();
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but the issue that occurs is that I cant access the getters from A

Comment: There are no getters from A, aside from those on `Object`. If you want your `getBuilder()` method to access methods specific to `Integer`, you would need to add the extra type parameter to the class.

Comment: I can not seem to get around it. I've tried both ways but I end up having to access getters of A.. Would using `@SuppressWarnings` be "ok" at this point or should I add another method to the interface which leads to the affected classes having to implement a method that will do nothing expect for the one class where it will be used and vice versa.

Comment: No, it would not be OK, other than in the code given, where you are returning `null` instead of an actual `Builder`. See [this code](https://ideone.com/qrzKX5), it compiles with no warning.